# Get first and last n items from a nodelist

Tags: javascript

I have a nodelist

```
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
        <li>Five</li>
    </ul>
```

```
const slides = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');
```

I want to save copies of first and last 2 li elements to a variable.

```
const first2 = slides.slice(0, 2),
  last2 = slides.slice(-2);
```

All the answers I've seen suggest creating array from nodelist but I need these elements to remain a nodelist. How can I do this?

I want to create clones of these items, add a class to it and add it back to ul. So the final html should look like this

```
<ul>
    <li class="copy">One</li>
    <li class="copy">Two</li>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li class="copy">Four</li>
    <li class="copy">Five</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What's the problem of your implementation?

Comment: " I need these elements to remain a nodelist" — Why? I can't think of anything you can do with a static node list that you can't do with an array.

Comment: Are you asking an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: You can also consider using something like [`nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) to make your selector more specific to select the actual items you're after

Comment: I need to make a clone of those items add a specific class to it and add them back into the ul. Updating the question.

Comment: @Whip, You don't need to clone them if you just need to add a specific class to them.

Comment: See my updated question with example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
const slides = document.querySelectorAll("ul li");
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");

const temp = [];
slides.forEach(slide => {
    const clone = slide.cloneNode(true);
    clone.classList.add("red");
    temp.push(clone);
});

temp.slice(0, 2).reverse().forEach(slide => {
    ul.prepend(slide);
});

temp.slice(-2).forEach(slide => {
    ul.appendChild(slide);
});
```

```css
.red {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can you selector like in CSS. In this case `:first-child` and `:last-child`

```js
const firstElement = document.querySelector('ul li:first-child');
console.log('firstElement', firstElement)

const lastElement = document.querySelector('ul li:last-child');
console.log('lastElement', lastElement)
```

```css
ul li:first-child {
  color:red;
}

ul li:last-child {
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```